# Swift: Add empty element in table view (Core Data)

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I want to add a 'new element' cell to my UITableView so that after text typing and tapping 'Enter' the new entry must be created. Something like [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yKmrr.png) but only in the end of the list. How can I do this? In my UITableViewController I use NSFetchedResultsController that handles operations with Core Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to amend the tableView delegate and datasource methods to include the extra row:

1. Add another prototype cell to your storyboard to represent your "extra" row.  Design it accordingly (subclassing if necessary) and assign it a different cell identifier.
2. Amend `numberOfRowsInSection` to return the FRC sectionInfo count *plus one*
3. Amend `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to dequeue with the different cell identifier if `indexPath.row` is equal to the FRC sectionInfo count (ie. the last row).  Configure the cell accordingly.
4. Amend `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to trigger the code to add the new entry.
5. Check/amend all other delegate/datasource methods (eg. `editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath`) to ensure they check the `indexPath.row` and handle the extra row appropriately.